# Print text between two patterns not containing a particular word

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, text

I want to print some text between two patterns which doesn't contain a particular word

### input text is

```
HEADER asdf asd 
asd COW assd
TAIL sdfsdfs
HEADER asdf asd
sdfsd DOG sdfsdfsdf
TAIL sdfsdfs

HEADER asdf asd
sdfsd MONKEY sdfsdfsdf
TAIL sdfsdfs
```

### output needed is

```
HEADER asdf asd
asd COW assd
TAIL sdfsdfs

HEADER asdf asd
sdfsd MONKEY sdfsdfsdf
TAIL sdfsdfs
```

---

conceptually something like this is needed

```
awk '/HEADER/,!/DOG/,TAIL' text
```

Comment: The empty line in your output is not between HEADER and TAIL in your input file so be more specific as to what should be preserved in the output...

Comment: Can you `HEAD` or `TAIL` lines contain `DOG`? If yes, is that ground for exclusion?

Comment: HEAD OR TAIL will not contain DOG. I just have to skip the whole segments(between HEAD and TAIL,both inclusive) if there is a DOG between the HEAD and TAIL.

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -lne 'print for grep !/DOG/, /^HEADER.*?TAIL.*?\n/mgs' your-file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '! inside {if (/^HEADER/) {inside = 1; skip = 0; content = ""} else next}
     /DOG/{skip = 1; next}
     ! skip {content=content $0 "\n"}
     /^TAIL/ {if (!skip) printf "%s", content; inside = 0}' your-file
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no other limitation here your script

```
sed '/^HEADER/{:1;N;/TAIL/!b1;/DOG/d}' text
```

Just for fun other variants of `awk`:
one:

```
awk '
    BEGIN{prn=1}
    /^HEADER/{block=1}
    block{
        if(/DOG/)
            prn=0
        if(!/^TAIL/){
            line=line $0 "\n"
            next
            }
        }
    prn{print line $0}
    /^TAIL/{
        block=0
        prn=1
        line=""
        }
' text
```

two:

```
awk '
    /^HEADER/{
        line=$0
        while(!/TAIL/){
            getline
            line=line "\n" $0
            }
        if(line !~ /DOG/)
            print line
        next
        }
    1' text
```